# create a new column based on the subtraction results from two columns

Tags: r

I have two large data sets like these:

```
df1=data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 10)), day =c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15,19,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15),stime=c('4/16/2012 6:25','4/16/2012 7:01','4/16/2012 17:22','4/16/2012 17:45','4/16/2012 18:13','4/18/2012 6:50','4/19/2012 6:55','5/1/2012 6:28','5/1/2012 7:00','5/1/2012 16:28','5/1/2012 17:00','5/5/2012 17:00','4/23/2012 5:56','4/23/2012 6:30','4/23/2012 16:55','4/23/2012 17:20','4/25/2012 6:32','4/26/2012 6:28','5/8/2012 5:54','5/8/2012 6:30','5/8/2012 15:55','5/8/2012 16:30'))

df2=data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)), day=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,9,9,15,15,1,1,2,2,3,3,9,9,15,15),dtime=c('4/16/2012 6:15','4/16/2012 15:16','4/18/2012 7:15','4/18/2012 21:45','4/19/2012 7:05','4/19/2012 23:17','4/28/2012 7:15','4/28/2012 21:12','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 15:15','4/23/2012 6:45','4/23/2012 16:45','4/25/2012 6:45','4/25/2012 21:30','4/26/2012 6:45','4/26/2012 22:00','5/2/2012 7:00','5/2/2012 22:00','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 15:45'))
```

...

in df2, the 'dtime' contains two time points for each subject on each day. I want to use the time points for each sub on each day in df1 (ie. 'stime') to subtract the second time point for each sub on each day in df2, if the result is positive, then give the second time point in dtime for that observation, otherwise give the first time point. For example, for subject 1 on day 1, ('4/16/2012 6:25'-'4/16/2012 15:16')<0, so we give the first time point '4/16/2012 6:15' to this obs; ('4/16/2012 17:22'-'4/16/2012 15:16')>0,
so we give this second time point '4/16/2012 15:16' to this obs. The expected output should look like this:

```
df3=data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 10)), day =c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15,19,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15),stime=c('4/16/2012 6:25','4/16/2012 7:01','4/16/2012 17:22','4/16/2012 17:45','4/16/2012 18:13','4/18/2012 6:50','4/19/2012 6:55','5/1/2012 6:28','5/1/2012 7:00','5/1/2012 16:28','5/1/2012 17:00','5/5/2012 17:00','4/23/2012 5:56','4/23/2012 6:30','4/23/2012 16:55','4/23/2012 17:20','4/25/2012 6:32','4/26/2012 6:28','5/8/2012 5:54','5/8/2012 6:30','5/8/2012 15:55','5/8/2012 16:30'), dtime=c('4/16/2012 6:15','4/16/2012 6:15','4/16/2012 15:16','4/16/2012 15:16','4/16/2012 15:16','4/18/2012 7:15','4/19/2012 7:05','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 15:15','5/1/2012 15:15','.','4/23/2012 6:45','4/23/2012 6:45','4/23/2012 16:45','4/23/2012 16:45','4/25/2012 6:45','4/26/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 15:45','5/8/2012 15:45'))
```

...

I used the code below to realize this, however, due to the missing 'dtime' for day 19, R kept giving me the error:

```
df1$dtime <- apply(df1, 1, function(x){  
                  choices <- df2[ df2$subject==as.numeric(x["subject"]) & 
                                       df2$day==as.numeric(x["day"]) , "dtime"]
         if( as.POSIXct(x["stime"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") < 
                 as.POSIXct(choices[2],format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") ) {
            choices[1] 
            }else{ choices[2] } 
                                  } )

Error in if (as.POSIXct(x["stime"], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") < as.POSIXct(choices[2],  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I inputted the two data frames in to try things out. Here is what I am thinking in terms of a pseudo-code approach (will leave you to finish the code). df1, when inputted, looks like the following:

```
   subject day           stime
1        1   1  4/16/2012 6:25
2        1   1  4/16/2012 7:01
3        1   1 4/16/2012 17:22
4        1   1 4/16/2012 17:45
5        1   1 4/16/2012 18:13
6        1   2  4/18/2012 6:50
7        1   3  4/19/2012 6:55
8        1  15   5/1/2012 6:28
9        1  15   5/1/2012 7:00
10       1  15  5/1/2012 16:28
11       1  15  5/1/2012 17:00
12       2   1  4/23/2012 5:56
13       2   1  4/23/2012 6:30
14       2   1 4/23/2012 16:55
15       2   1 4/23/2012 17:20
16       2   2  4/25/2012 6:32
17       2   3  4/26/2012 6:28
18       2  15   5/8/2012 5:54
19       2  15   5/8/2012 6:30
20       2  15  5/8/2012 15:55
21       2  15  5/8/2012 16:30
```

Why not try the following:

- First, write a simple loop that will enable you to loop through each of the values in the stime column for both df1 and df2. Do make this easy, you could convert the df1 and df2 data frame into a matrix if you like (using as.matrix(), which is my preference).
- After you grab the first value in row 1, column, 3 from df1, which is 4/16/2012 6:25, pull out the 6:25 and store it in a temporary variable ... let's call this variable a
- Do the exact same thing for df2, which you also want to compare to, and store this in a temporary variable, except grab the variable from the relevant position ... let's call this variable b
- Subtract the two temporary variables (you may need to write some code to get the two parts set up so that you can easily do an a-b and get a numerical answer. That said, I will leave that up to you).
- Check whether the answer is positive or negative using a simple conditional if statement
- Get the value of a or b depending on the output from your conditional check
- Add this new value to a new data table, with the appropriate subject and day. You have called this df3.

Comment: You do not seem to have a good sense of what data types have the subtraction operation defined for them. See `?Ops` to improve your grasp.

Comment: Good catch. I should clarify. I am fully aware that 6:25 is not in a format that will allow easy subtraction. That said, the solution above should still hold, contingent on the fact that you put the format in a form that enables you to "difference" the two time points. I have done this before on a large scale for time series analysis, which is why I noted the following in my answer: "You may need to write some code to get the two parts set up so that you can easily do an a-b and get a numerical answer. That said, I will leave that up to you."

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting different answers than you. First I made a copy of df1 to work with:

```
df4 <- df1
df4$dtime <- apply(df4, 1, function(x){  
                      choices <- df2[ df2$subject==as.numeric(x["subject"]) & 
                                           df2$day==as.numeric(x["day"]) , "dtime"]
             if( as.POSIXct(x["stime"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") < 
                     as.POSIXct(choices[1],format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") ) {
                choices[1] 
                }else{ choices[2] } 
                                      } )
#----------------------------------------------
   subject day           stime           dtime
1        1   1  4/16/2012 6:25 4/16/2012 15:16
2        1   1  4/16/2012 7:01 4/16/2012 15:16
3        1   1 4/16/2012 17:22 4/16/2012 15:16
4        1   1 4/16/2012 17:45 4/16/2012 15:16
5        1   1 4/16/2012 18:13 4/16/2012 15:16
6        1   2  4/18/2012 6:50  4/18/2012 7:15
7        1   3  4/19/2012 6:55  4/19/2012 7:05
8        1  15   5/1/2012 6:28   5/1/2012 7:15
9        1  15   5/1/2012 7:00   5/1/2012 7:15
10       1  15  5/1/2012 16:28  5/1/2012 15:15
11       1  15  5/1/2012 17:00  5/1/2012 15:15
12       2   1  4/23/2012 5:56  4/23/2012 6:45
13       2   1  4/23/2012 6:30  4/23/2012 6:45
14       2   1 4/23/2012 16:55 4/23/2012 16:45
15       2   1 4/23/2012 17:20 4/23/2012 16:45
16       2   2  4/25/2012 6:32  4/25/2012 6:45
17       2   3  4/26/2012 6:28  4/26/2012 6:45
18       2  15   5/8/2012 5:54   5/8/2012 6:45
19       2  15   5/8/2012 6:30   5/8/2012 6:45
20       2  15  5/8/2012 15:55  5/8/2012 15:45
21       2  15  5/8/2012 16:30  5/8/2012 15:45
```

Comment: your code worked, the only thing that made the different output is that we should use choice[2] instead of choice[1] in the as.POSIXct() statement.

Comment: However, R gave me the error msg: Error in if (as.POSIXct(x["SPI1O"], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") < as.POSIXct(choices[2],  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I replaced the missing values with "." in both df1 and df2, but the error is still there. Do you have any means to avoid this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have options("stringsAsFators") set to FALSE, so in the creation of htose dataframe I would that been getting character rather than factor columns. You could convert the date-time columns to class-"character" with code like `df1$stime<- as.character( df1$stime)`.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply! But after setting stringsAsFators to FALSE and converting the date-time columns to character, the error is still there. So I removed the rows with missing values in 'stime' and 'dtime', but the error is not gone.

Comment: There were no NA values in the example and you did not say what to do if one were encountered.

Comment: ya, I was just want to show an example, but the actual data is large, there are some missing observations in it